# asp.net Gridview checkbox is clickable without edit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a checkbox on my griview and its able to be clicked before the edit button is clicked, this doesn't make sense to me and its not something I have came across before. In theory the checkbox should be greyed out until a user clicks the edit button.

Nothing can be updated but it just doesn't make any sense as to why this functionality would be available. I have set up Gridviews before using checkboxes and never came across this. Below is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLeagues" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
            onpageindexchanging="gvLeagues_PageIndexChanging"  
            onrowcancelingedit="gvLeagues_RowCancelingEdit"  
            onrowdatabound="gvLeagues_RowDataBound"
            onrowediting="gvLeagues_RowEditing" 
            onrowupdating="gvLeagues_RowUpdating"  
            onsorting="gvLeagues_Sorting" EnableModelValidation="True"          
            CssClass="footable"
            EditRowStyle-CssClass="table table-bordered" >
```

No Data Found.

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>            

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created Date" SortExpression="CreatedDate">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Bind("CreatedDate")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreatedDate")%>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>            

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day" SortExpression="Day">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Day")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Day")%>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Season" SortExpression="Season">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Season")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Season")%>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enabled" SortExpression="Enabled">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnabled" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Enabled")%>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnabled" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Enabled")%>' /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the ItemTemplate, you are the one specifying what and how you want to see it. Just set that checkbox as [disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enabled" SortExpression="Enabled">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnabled" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Enabled")%>' />
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate><asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnabled" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Enabled")%>'  enabled="False"/></ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```